# ERROR #NUM! from sum of largest 5 numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The aim:

1. Get the largest 5 numbers from (W115:AO115)
   e.g. (5,5,5,5,4,3,3)==> Get (5,5,5,5,4)
2. Add them together ,i.e . 5+5+5+5+4=24

My formula is :`=LARGE(W115:AO115,1)+LARGE(W115:AO115,2)+LARGE(W115:AO115,3)+LARGE(W115:AO115,4)+LARGE(W115:AO115,5)`

`#NUM!` ERROR happens ,I guess the reason is there is no 5 numbers in this row

In fact `U` should be count as `0` .
The result of this row (2,4,U,3,U,3) should be `12`.
How to solve this case?

[image: Excel table]

Comment: Try wrapping within in `IFERROR()` `=SUM(IFERROR(LARGE(W115:AO115,{1,2,3,4,5}),""))`

Comment: Also instead of hard coding {1,2,3,4,5} like this you can use `=SUM(IFERROR(LARGE(W115:AO115,ROW($1:$5)),""))`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Tried, one of data in a row containing `#VALUE!` ,It outputs 0

Comment: You need to press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` if you are not using `MS365` or try this one then `=SUM(IFERROR(LARGE(IFERROR(W115:AO115,""),ROW($1:$5)),""))`

Comment: What is your excel version? You may try `AGGREGATE()` function to ignore errors.

Comment: Even using `AGGREGATE()` you may get the `#NUM!` error, `=SUM(IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14,6,W115:AO115,ROW($1:$5)),""))` need to wrap within `IFERROR()`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Why `H5:Z5 ?`

Comment: aah edited now, should be `W115:AO115`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Seems ok, you want to answer it ?

Comment: Ok. Updating in answers.

Comment: then I will mark correct

Comment: Here is another way, which works as well. `=SUM(AGGREGATE(14,6,ISNUMBER(W115:AO115)*W115:AO115,ROW($1:$5)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid errors like `#NUM!` or `#VALUE!` need to wrap within `IFERROR()`

Use either,

```
=SUM(IFERROR(LARGE(IFERROR(W115:AO115,""),ROW($1:$5)),""))
```

Or, as mentioned above by Harun Sir, using `AGGREGATE()` still needs to wrap within `IFERROR()`

```
=SUM(IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14,6,W115:AO115,ROW($1:$5)),""))
```

Edit,

One more way, without using `IFERROR()` instead using `ISNUMBER()`

```
=SUM(AGGREGATE(14,6,ISNUMBER(W115:AO115)*W115:AO115,ROW($1:$5)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Sort in Excel 365, assuming they are positive numbers:

```
=SUM(INDEX(SORT(N(+W115:AO115),,-1,1),SEQUENCE(5)))
```